# How to judge whether a relation is true or false

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities, logic

$x$ is a real number, how to judge $x+1>x$ is true using Wolfram.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FullSimplify`,

```
FullSimplify[x + 1 > x, x \[Element] Reals]
```

> True

Comment: You don't need `FullSimplify`, `Simplify` suffices. Also, you don't need the assumption: `Simplify` implicitly assumes you're dealing with reals: this is, arguably, incorrect behavior. `Reduce` is more rigorous: `Reduce[x + 1 > x, Reals]` yields `True`, but it needs the domain specification.

Comment: @JohnDoty - Behavior of `Simplify` is documented. Documentation states: "Quantities that appear algebraically in inequalities are always assumed to be real." Similarly, documentation for `Reduce` states: "Reduce[expr, vars] assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex. " With v11.3 on my Mac, `Reduce[x+1 > x]` and `Reduce[x+1 > x, x]` evaluate to `Element[x, Reals]` which, while more rigorous, is inconsistent with documentation.